# How to convert Json to Python object?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How to convert the complex Json format to python? I feel difficulty in converting the attached complex json to python object and I have to validate this data later against the DB.

Json:

```
{
   "namespace":"Data.Datapoint",
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Blood Donar",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "type":"int"
      },
      {
         "name":"donor_number",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"birth_date",
         "type":{
            "type":"int",
            "logicalType":"date"
         },
         "doc":"Birth Date"
      },
      {
         "name":"height",
         "type":[
            "int",
            "null"
         ],
         "doc":"Height"
      },
      {
         "name":"applicant_ts",
         "type":[
            {
               "type":"long",
               "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
            },
            "null"
         ],
         "doc":"Creation Timestamp"
      },
      {
         "name":"arm_preference_ind",
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ],
         "doc":"Arm Preference; Selection from list"
      },
      {
         "name":"abo_ind",
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ],
         "doc":"Blood Type/ABO"
      },
      {
         "name":"vein_grading_ind",
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ],
         "doc":"Vein Grade"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using `json.loads`? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

data = '''
{ "namespace": "Data.Datapoint", "type": "record", "name": "Blood Donar", "fields": [ { "name": "id", "type": "int" }, { "name": "donor_number", "type": "string" }, { "name": "birth_date", "type": { "type": "int", "logicalType": "date" }, "doc": "Birth Date" }, { "name": "height", "type": [ "int", "null" ], "doc": "Height" }, { "name": "applicant_ts", "type": [ { "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis" }, "null" ], "doc": "Creation Timestamp" }, { "name": "arm_preference_ind", "type": [ "string", "null" ], "doc": "Arm Preference; Selection from list" }, { "name": "abo_ind", "type": [ "string", "null" ], "doc": "Blood Type/ABO" }, { "name": "vein_grading_ind", "type": [ "string", "null" ], "doc": "Vein Grade" } ] }
'''

json_data = json.loads(data)
```

`json_data` is your python dict obj.

if you want json data from web you can try this

```
import json
import requests
response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
todos = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: If you are getting back json from the web you can do `response.json()` if you get an error with that then remove the `()`